# barometer app for Android

Tags: android

There are hundreth of Barometer Apps out on Play.

Which one is without Ads, free and uses the least permissions?

(Or How could I find out this myself without looking at each detail page in Play?)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **[Barometer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/barometer/com.farproc.barometer)**:

- **uses the least permissions:** 0 permissions. Less is impossible.
- **without Ads:** no permissions, no ads (as they cannot be loaded from the network)
- **free:** as in "free beer", yes. Not sure whether it's open source as well ;)

For alternatives, you might wish to take a look at [my app lists](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=164#group_867). At a glance you can see here rating (ordered by that, decending, so the best rated apps come first), price, number of permissions, and more – right from the list, so no need to call up "detail pages". You can even [search apps by permission](http://android.izzysoft.de/catmin/applists.php?topic=search), i.e. list apps for given categories which do (not) have specific permissions you name (see also: [How to search the Play Store by permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/69964/16575) on Android.SE).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [**Barometer Reborn**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.apps.barometer)

- it is battery friendly
- no ads
- nice material look
- charts

It has only location permission for My Places functionality. If you don't use My Places functionality then it does not fetch location.

More info about the app at https://www.barometer-reborn.com/